# Предлагаю объединить метки “запятая” и “запятые”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “запятая” и “запятые”. Мне кажется, мы отдаем предпочтение множественному числу. Тогда пусть метка “запятые” будет главной, а “запятая” – синонимом.

Answer (score 1):

Метки объединены, синонимы созданы. Спасибо за помощь!